# Android: cannot see app name in data\data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I tried to use SQLite on Android. I want to see my database file. So, I use `Android File Explorer` and browse this link:
`Data\data\App_name` But in `Data\data`. I cannot see my app name. (in below code will be: com/app/TimeTracker)

Here my code to test:

first is my main program:

```
package com.app;
    public class TimeTrackerActivity extends Activity {    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            TimeTrackerDatabase database = new TimeTrackerDatabase(this);
        }
    }
```

and second is my database helper:

```
package com.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TimeTrackerDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TimeTrackerDatabase(Context context){
        super(context, "timetracker.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE timerecords"+"id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time TEXT, notes TEXT)"
        );
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

}
```

Is there any problem in above two file ? If has, please tell me what. And if not, please tell me how to fix this problem.

thanks :)

@Edit: I add my screenshot of my data folder. (No file in lib folder)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: if you are not root - you can't see /data/data

Comment: I'm using Android Emulator. I can see data/data, but cannot see my app. And, how can I know root or not. And if not, how to be a root user ?

Comment: Even if you are root, it doesn't mean anything.  Many production builds do not allow acces to this directory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the database related issue will be solved by below updation in your code.

```
package com.app;
    public class TimeTrackerActivity extends Activity {    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            TimeTrackerDatabase database = new TimeTrackerDatabase(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();   //Add this line.
        }
    }

public class TimeTrackerDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TimeTrackerDatabase(Context context){
        super(context, "timetracker.db", null, 2);

    }


@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

     database.execSQL(

                "CREATE TABLE timerecords" +
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time TEXT, notes TEXT)"

        );

    }
```

Regarding your app not visible in File explorer, you need to search by package name as below
data/data/com.app and here you can see database folder where you can see all your databases created by applicatio[image]n

Comment: how to search something in `File Explorer' Sorry, but I cannot find search button. (and Control + F)

Comment: oh I mean you have to manually check whether the folder name having package name of your application exist in data->data

Comment: I checked and run the code in my eclipse the folder is there but db doesn't exist...uploaded a screen shot in original answer..

Comment: hey man your not getting my point, you have to expand name field in file explorer by stretching it by mouse at the top from divider

Comment: No please try to understand me, the name field is not showing complete names of all the folders they are shrinked to show only "con", So please expand the name field in File explorer to check the full name of each folder if you won't see the folder names correctly then how can u check the files...If you want then I can come on chat to tell you

Comment: Oh :-O I don't have any words to sorry to you :( So stupid !!! (maybe because I meet this error and don't think carefully anything around ). I have understand you and upload new image. Please watch it for me. Again, I'm so sorry with you :(

Comment: Ok I updated the answer. Now your complete solution is in my answer. I have ran the same. Please check

Comment: Oh. THANKS :) So GREAT!!! With your answer guest me, I google many times and understand why :) Again, thanks for your pleasant help me tonight:)

Answer (score 0):

actually your database is not being created due to faulty query.

write your query as:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS timerecords
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time TEXT, notes TEXT);"
```

once, the db file is created, then you can browse till the desired location

Comment: are looking for the **db** file on your sd card's Data folder?

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me where sd card's data folder in `Folder Explorer`, please. I don't see anythings like Sd data when view in  `Folder Explorer`. Thanks :)

Comment: yes, I see folder `SDCard` in folder `MNT`. in this folder, I just see two emty folder that `DSI` and `LOS`. Can you give more some idea, please. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not Data\data\App_name , it'll be Data\data\package_name. So in your case it'll be Data\data\com.app\
Try looking your db file there.

Comment: Oh. yes. `Data\data\com.app\` Just my fault when Typing :(